# How does the USA IRS determine the yearly average exchange rate?

Tags: foreign-exchange, irs

The USA IRS publishes a [list of yearly exchange rates](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/yearly-average-currency-exchange-rates) titled **Yearly Average Exchange Rates for Converting Foreign Currencies into U.S. Dollars**. As of this writing, the published average value for USDCNY over 2017 is `7.030`.

This came across as odd, so I looked up a chart and marked off the beginning and end of 2017 (vertical blue lines) as well as the published average (horizontal green line):

[image: Tradingview USDCNY 2017]

My question is (only) how the IRS' published average value is determined. The value is provided to three decimal places, which suggests it is calculated somehow. I appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this.